# HIVE - How to extract hashtags from a string in HIVE

Tags: sql, regex, split, hive, substr

IF we have a sample field say 'note'
note could be in (
'xyz #abc-xyz-dfg. #abd'
,
'#123%36&89'

, '## avc #1 "Changed xyz #2 from "string"\n - stop #3 #'

)

What I am doing is
-`REGEXP_EXTRACT( regexp_replace( upper(note),'.?(\\#\\w+)' ' $1' ), '.(\\#\\w+)', 0 )`

But what it is doing is:

if we have a tag as #abc-xyz it's only fetching #abc instead of #abc-xyz

or a tag as #abc-xyz. #abcd it's only fetching #abcd instead of #abc-xyz #abcd

Or if we have #1 or #2, it's skipping it, giving nulls

or if we have #123%36&89 , it's giving #123, we need complete

**Edit:**
**Solution :**

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(
      regexp_replace(
        upper(note),
        '.*?(#[\w?\d?\\`\\~!@#$%\\^&*-_+{}\\[\\]\\|//?;:\\"]+)',
        ' $1'
      ),
      '.*(#[\w?\d?\\`\\~!@#$%\\^&*-_+{}\\[\\]\\|//?;:\\"]+)',
      0
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which doesn't contain `-`, `%`, or `&`. Instead of using `\w`, you should define a character set that contains everything that you want to match, such as `[a-zA-Z0-9_%&-]`.

Note that `-` must be included as either the first or last character in the set in order for it to treated as a literal. When it exists between two characters it defines a range.

Comment: hey, could you please share a comparison string? I tried adding but it's not working somehow. I might not be doing it right.